# Executing Batch File From Shortcut

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to execute a batch file from a shortcut application on my desktop. The batch file lives on my C:drive which is where the actual application.exe is.

The problem is the CMD is executing the batch from C:\Users\hap\Desctop> and not from the executable path so it obviously cannot find my .exe file that the batch file is looking for.

Here is what I am using to execute the batch file:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\batch_file.bat").WaitForExit();
```

Comment: You don't need the GetDirectoryName call. If I'm not mistaken, the ExecutablePath property already contains the full path.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the problem has something to do with the length of the directory names.

Comment: Solution: I am using the InstallShield to setup a .msi so, there is a setting to change the working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is create a `ProcessStartInfo` structure and set its `WorkingDirectory` appropriately.

You should do the following:

```
string workingDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = workingDir + "\\batch_file.bat",
    WorkingDirectory = workingDir // or wherever else you want it to execute from
};
Process p = new Process() { StartInfo = info };
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```